# Aspera Error :- ascp.exe: Failed to open TCP connection for SSH, exiting

Tags: c#, ssh, console-application

I am working on Aspera file upload functionality and I am getting one error as per below scenario.

I downloaded Aspera CLI from below URL.
https://downloads.asperasoft.com/en/downloads/62

and then with the help of command prompt ran below statement and it worked fine.

> cmd Statement : ascp -P33001 -QT -l500m --file-manifest=text -k 0 -o
>   Overwrite=always {Source File Path} {username}@{domain}:{destination
>   Folder}

It worked perfectly fine.

Then I tried the same thing from console app with below code.

```
Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo.FileName = @"E:\Projects\Research\AsperaFileUpload\AsperaFileUpload\AsperaLibrary\bin\ascp.exe";
                process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"ascp -P33001 -QT -l500m --file-manifest=text -k 0 -o Overwrite=always {Source File Path} {username}@{domain}:{destination Folder}"; // Note the /c command (*)

                process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                process.Start();
                //* Read the output (or the error)
                string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(output); 
                string err = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(err);
                Console.ReadLine();
                process.WaitForExit();
```

But this code always give error like "ascp.exe: Failed to open TCP connection for SSH, exiting"

I am wondering if same command working from command line why it is not working from console app.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This error message tells that "ascp" cannot connect to TCP port 33001 (arg "-P") of the server "{domain}"

I suggest the following:

1. use the more modern syntax:

   ```
   ascp -P33001 -QT -l500m --file-manifest=text -k 0 -o Overwrite=always --host={domain} --user={username} --mode=send {Source File Path} {destination Folder}
   ```
2. add argument `-L /path/to/log/folder` and look at log error in file: aspera-scp-transfer.log
3. instead of using bare "ascp", which you will find limited, prefer to use the "TransferSDK" here:
   https://developer.ibm.com/aspera